# Process ID of a browser window Microsoft Explorer

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, powershell-2.0

Is there any way to get the process ID of a browser windows ?, when I have multiple browser windows open?

```
$windowTitle='Facebook(.*?)'
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle -match $windowtitle} | 
Format-Table Id, Name, mainWindowtitle -AutoSize
```

With this I can only search for the main window title.

Comment: You are using a [Wildcard comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) pattern with the [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6) `-match` operator. In this case using `-like` would be better.

Comment: @Theo Nothing to complain about `Facebook(.*?)` a completely valid RegEx, verify the explanation on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ftKwk1/1), albeit the `(.*?)` part is superfluous unless you ***use***. the matches collection.

Comment: Are you refering to separate windows or tabs? What IE version? This article may be relevant https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/finding-the-thread-pid-that-belongs-to-a-tab-in-ie-8-with-powershell/

Comment: @LotPings Ah, yes I see now. Must have dozed off or something. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to refer PowerShell script below which will give you process id of each windows with its title. Further you can modify the script as per your requirement.

Example script:

```
$sig = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetTopWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

public enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint {
    GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
    GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
    GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
    GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
    GW_OWNER = 4,
    GW_CHILD = 5,
    GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
"@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Namespace User32 -Name Util -UsingNamespace System.Text

$iethreads = get-process iexplore |?{!$_.MainWindowTitle} |%{$_.ID}

$p=0
$window = [User32.Util]::GetTopWindow(0)

while ($window -ne 0) {
    [User32.util]::GetWindowThreadProcessId($window, [ref]$p) |out-null
    if ($iethreads -contains $p) {
        $length = [User32.Util]::GetWindowTextLength($window)
        if ($length -gt 0) {
            $string = New-Object System.Text.Stringbuilder 1024
            [User32.Util]::GetWindowText($window,$string,($length+1)) |out-null
            if ($string.tostring() -notmatch '^MSCTFIME UI$|^Default IME$|^SysFader$|^MCI command handling window$') {
                new-object psobject -Property @{PID = $p;Title = $string.tostring()}
            }
        }
    }
    $window = [User32.Util]::GetWindow($window, 2)
}
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:

[Finding the thread (PID) that belongs to a tab in IE with PowerShell](https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/finding-the-thread-pid-that-belongs-to-a-tab-in-ie-8-with-powershell/)